# PHP sprintf for latitude longitude values, use %f or %d or %F or something else?

Tags: php, geolocation, concatenation, character, printf

This question title is a bit longer than what I intended, but I'm wondering what's the best % character to use for `sprintf`, for something like this:

`sprintf("Show lat=%f AND lng=%f",$lat,$lng)`

Where `$lat` and `$lng` are latitude and longitude coordinate values (respectively) that are parsed into variables from `$_REQUEST`, i.e.:

```
$lat = $_REQUEST['lat'];
$lng = $_REQUEST['lng'];
```

Sample values are: `test.php?lat=37.8019444&lng=-122.4327778`

---

As mentioned below, the type specifiers for `sprintf` are indeed listed in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), but for someone who is not familiar with the type specifiers, the parameter descriptions are very confusing... which is why I am asking the question here.

Comment: What format are the values in? Can you show an example?

Comment: $lat and $lng are typical latitude and longitude values that are from $_REQUEST, such as $lat = 37.8019444; $lng = -122.4327778. See updated.

Comment: The best option only depends on the type of vars stored in $lat, $lng You have a description of all type specifier characters here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: (Updated with the source of the variables)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the manual page, but it's confusing what it considers a %f locale-aware float vs %F non-locale aware float. (What does Locale refer to?) I am also not sure what %d means with argument treated as an integer, presented as signed decimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I *had* to format the values as a number, my choice would be `%F`:

> F - the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number (non-locale aware). Available since PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.3.

A non-locale aware representation is necessary because otherwise, the european representation would look like `xx,xxxxxx` for example - quite possibly breaking the value for your intended purpose.

That said, I'm not sure whether it's wise to format these values at all. Depending on what you're going to use them for, it might make sense to just pass them through as strings (after escaping them against SQL injection, of course.)

Comment: How is the locale-aware setting determined?

Comment: I have encountered a bug once using a locale-aware function for longitude and lattitude, took me quite some time to find it. +1 from me!

Comment: Also, what is the floating point precision? Is %F only 6 decimal digits?

Comment: Also, would %s ever be appropriate when the arguments are not strings?

Comment: @ina 1. `setlocale()` 2. tbh I don't know what the default precision is; you can define your own using the precision specifier 3. if you don't want `sprintf()` to *format* the values but you want to just pass them through, sure, use `%s`